# Durandal: Handling RequireJS errors when view/viewModel is not found

Tags: javascript, requirejs, durandal

Is it possible to add routes to Durandal for the purpose of displaying them in the navigation, but gracefully handle the RequireJS error when they can't be found?

E.g.: If we have 4 pages - Two are in progress, but 2 will be complete next month:

```
router.map([
           { route: ['', 'home'], moduleId: 'test/index', title: 'Almost finished', nav:                 
           { route: 'one', moduleId: 'test/one', title: 'In progress', nav: true },               
           { route: 'two', moduleId: 'test/two', title: 'Still to be complete', nav: true },                   
           { route: 'three', moduleId: 'test/three', title: 'Validation test', nav: true }
       ]).buildNavigationModel()
         .activate();
```

The [router.mapUnknownRoutes](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-The-Router/) method will only handle routes not in the router - e.g.: can give a graceful logger message for `'test/doesntexist'`, but will give a JS error (and crash the app) for `'test/three'`

Answer (score 2):

RequireJS does provide a way to handle errors that occur while trying to load a module.  You can provide specific handler for each module, or you can set up a global error handler.

See this link for more information:  http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#errors

- Load-failure handler:  http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#errbacks

If you use a load-failure handler, you can provide a fall-back, or default, module that should be returned. - Of course, when using with Durandal, this may cause Durandal to look for a different view, or depending on when Durandal derives the view id, you may end up with a mismatched view/view model pair.

- Global error handler:  http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#requirejsonerror

If you use the global handler, you'll have to take some corrective action, such as changing the window location to a different url in the case of failure.

Comment: Good to know. Are you using this in a specific scenario with Durandal?

Comment: I am using the global handler, but only logging errors at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Module loading is handled by `requirejs` and I doubt that there's a graceful way to handle this situation. But what about adding an empty `test/wip` module with an associated `test/wip.html` file that either display nothing or something like `work in progress`.